# Ubuntu 11.10- Conky (Need help w/ config)

Tags: 11.10, configuration, scripts, conky, system-monitor

I'm still new to ubuntu, I just downloaded "Conky" from the command line. I found some really cool script online, but I don't how to edit Conky and copy and paste the script.

Thanks,

-Vince

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page has over 4 million views. It's a great place to start with conky questions.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865&highlight=conky

[image]